# Why does Heroku think this remote exists?

Tags: git, heroku

My production app on Heroku works just fine, but I'm running into trouble trying to add a staging app:

```
$ heroku list
=== My Apps
testivate
testivate-staging

$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:testivate.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:testivate.git (push)

$ heroku git:remote -a testivate-staging
 !    Git remote heroku already exists
```

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Steven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`heroku git:remote` adds a remote called "heroku" by default.  The error message is telling you, "a git remote named heroku already exists".  Specify a name for your remote by appending `-r your_name`.

Comment: Thanks. "heroku git:remote -a testivate-staging -r staging" worked.